# Is it enough to delete operator=(Type type)?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is the following enough (from a best-practice perspective) for a nonmovable type?

```
class A
{
   A(const A&) = delete;
   A(A&&) = delete;
   A& operator=(A) = delete;
public:
   A();
};
```

Or do I have to delete the copy/move assignment operators separately? Also is a destructor required here?

Comment: the operator you're trying to delete is `A& operator=(const A&)`, I think

Comment: @Porges: No, I want to delete both `A& operator=(const A&)` **and** `A& operator=(A&&)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, declaring the copy constructor and copy assignment operators as `deleted` is enough. Since you are declaring a copy constructor and copy assignment operator the move constructor and move assignment operator will not be automatically generated. You do not need to explicitly declare them `deleted`.

From §12.8/9 (Emphasis added)

> If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted **if and only if**
>    — X does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
>    — X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
>    — X does not have a user-declared move assignment operator,
>    — X does not have a user-declared destructor, and
>    — the move constructor would not be implicitly defined as deleted.

From §12.8/20 (Emphasis added)

> If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move assignment operator, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted **if and only if**
>   — X does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
>   — X does not have a user-declared move constructor,
>   — X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
>   — X does not have a user-declared destructor, and
>   — the move assignment operator would not be implicitly defined as deleted.

Comment: Is this with the latest rules for this? I remember there was a lot of discussion and changes to these rules during standardization.

Comment: The above text is from the C++11 Standard (ISO 14882-2012). There is a C++14 proposal ([N3578 - The Rule of Five"](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3578.pdf)) which might be what you are thinking about. If approved you'll be able to remove _either_ the copy constructor or copy assignment operator from your example and get the same affect as declaring them both deleted.

Answer (score 3):

According to [class.copy]/17 `operator=(A)` is a valid copy assignment operator, so yes, declaring it deleted is sufficient to suppress the implicit move assignment operator and therefore along with the deleted copy constructor will make the class non-copyable and non-movable.

Your class is more complicated than necessary though, all you need is:

```
class A
{
   A(const A&) = delete;
   A& operator=(A) = delete;
public:
   A();
};
```

The user-declared copy constructor suppresses the implicit move constructor, and the user-declared copy assignment operator suppresses the implicit move assignment operator.

However, the `operator=(A)` form is un-idiomatic, so I would tend to use `operator=(const A&) = delete` anyway. It has the same effect.

N.B. there is no reason to declare deleted functions private, and in fact it results in much worse diagnostics.  Public and deleted works better in my experience.

> Also is a destructor required here?

Required for what?  It depends what your default constructor does.

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to have a user defined destructor, just to respect the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) (or five), if there's no other reason.

Comment: I don’t think `operator=(A)` is particularly unidiomatic any more. It’s been advocated extensively in the wake of (and even before!) C++11 supporting compilers. Of course it doesn’t make a difference *in this case* where it’s only deleted – but when *implementing* it I would tend to advise using the new idiom throughout.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, when declaring a copy assignment operator purely for the the purposes of deleting it I would use `operator=(const A&)` for symmetry and consistency with the copy constructor, if nothing else. `A(A)` is not a valid copy constructor, obviously.